# Excel Data to TreeView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, treeview

I am looking to create a windows form that contains a tree view of data that I have in excel. I have the windows form I am just trying to figure out how to export the excel data into that data tree. Any links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly you can access Excel files and use every property and method easily.
Example:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static object GetCellValue(
       string filename, string sheet, int row, int column)
{
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Open(filename);
    Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[sheet];
    object ret = sh.Cells[row, column].Value2;
    wb.Close();
    excel.Quit();
}
```

Comment: I have this currently as an add in, so the data is already in the sheet and the add in will take the data to create the tree, would this work?

Comment: @Berbies: my example opens an excel file, gets a value from row/col in a sheet and close the file. You should open the file you want from C# app, get all the values you need, fill treeview and finally close excel file. It shouldn't be so hard I hope. If it is ask :)