# TreeView to Excel using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, treeview

I asked a question [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561216/excel-data-to-treeview-c) on how to take excel data and put it into a winforms treeview, the treeview works properly and I made it so you can make changes to the treeview such as adding new nodes to it. What I would like to do is export this into the sheet that I created for this export. Any ideas or links?

Thanks.

Comment: well, you got an answer to your linked question that shows you the interaction with excel, so i assume your question is more about how to get that treeview nodes into a 2D matrix representation like excel-cells... correct?

Comment: What I really want to do is read through the nodes and put them in a column for each child of the parent. So if you have Parent->Child->SubChild. One Column would have the Parent and in the same row in the next column would have the child, so on so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were approaching this problem I would probably convert the tree view into XML and then load the xml in by opening the file regularly.  If I knew more about the way you wanted your excel file to appear and what sort of information you are trying to retain from your treeview I could probably give a more comprehensive answer.

Other Peoples Examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/treeviewtoxml.aspx

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ms-office/excel/Load_An_XML_Document_Into_Excel.htm

Comment: I think once I get a better understanding of how it looks once it is loaded, then I can work on how to get it to appear a specific way. Thanks for the help.